# condition to provide zero value to the field if null and return subtracted two field in sap crystal reports

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, field, formula

Hello I am using Sap Crystal Report, in that I am using two field.

**Now, I want to provide 0 value to the null field and also return the subtracted two field.**

For more clear lets see my code,

**//Condition for null and provide 0 value to the field else same value to the field**

```
If IsNull({TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine}) or 
IsNull({TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine}) then

{TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine} = 0 or
{TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine} = 0

    else

    {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine} = {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine} or
    {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine} = {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine}
```

**//return subtrated two field value**

```
  {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine} - {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine}
```

now its showing error i.e. **The remaining text does not appear to the part of the formula**. I dont know whats the error indicating. I think so formula syntax is incorrect or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign values to database fields, but you can assign them to variables.

```
local numbervar PurchaseFine ;:= {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine} ;
local numbervar ReturnFine ; := {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine};

If IsNull({TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine}) Then
PurchaseFine := 0 
Else 
PurchaseFine := {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.PurchaseFine} ;

If IsNull({TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine}) Then
ReturnFine := 0 
Else 
ReturnFine := {TmpWholeSaleDetailItemReport.ReturnFine} ;

PurchaseFine - ReturnFine ;
```